# Low memory $_GET?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm creating a multi-threaded `random.org` number getter to implement into my c# IRC bot.  The issue I have is, it uses a moderately big memory footprint.  I think it's the `WebClient` class.  I dislike how it uses `~5,000K` memory just for connecting to the url, and reading the first line and outputting the number.

Is there a lighter approach to this?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Thread More = new Thread(GetRandomNum);
                More.Start();
            }
        }
        public static void GetRandomNum()
        {
            string number;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    number = client.DownloadString("http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(number.Trim());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use Random.org instead of a good crypto PRNG? I never found a convincing technical reason for choosing a RNG webservice over a crypto PRNG, and plenty of reasons to avoid it.

Comment: Well, I was trying to create a true random 1-100 dice roll for my IRC bot.  The PRNG was okay I guess, I just wanted it to be perfect:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) will do the trick.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

This looks very complicated, still the code is rather simple and straightforward.
Memory consumption must be much lower than with WebClient.